# Ubuntu 17.04 lists two nvidia kernel modules as installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, dkms

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 and `dkms status` lists the following two nvidia modules:

```
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.10.0-19-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.10.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I checked my kernel version, it's:

```
4.10.0-22-generic
```

Am I encouraged to remove the nvidia module for the older kernel version?

Or, are they supposed to live together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not two kernel modules, this is the same kernel module built for two different kernels: `4.10.0-19-generic` and `4.10.0-22-generic`.

You have both kernels installed.